# Why have the smaller array drive binary search when computing the median of two sorted arrays?

Tags: python, algorithm, median

A common algorithm for solving the problem of [finding the median of two sorted arrays](https://leetcode.com/problems/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/) of size `m` and `n` is to:

1. Run binary search to adjust "a cut" of the **smaller** array in two halves. When doing so, we adjust the cut of the **larger array** to make sure the total number of elements on the first halves of **both** arrays equals the total number of elements in the second halves of both arrays, which is a pre-condition for splitting both arrays around the median.
2. The binary search shifts the cuts left or right until all elements on the left halves <= all elements on the right halves.
3. At the end of the procedure, we can readily compute the median with a basic comparison of the elements on the boundary of the cuts of both arrays.

While I understand at a high level the algorithm, I'm not sure I understand why one needs to do the calculation on the smaller array, and adjust the larger array, as opposed to the other way around.

---

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPFhl65R7ww) a video explaining the algorithm, but the author doesn't explain exactly why we use the smaller array to drive the binary search.

I'm also including below Python code that is supposed to solve the problem, mostly to make the post self-contained, even if it's not well documented.

```
def median(A, B):
    m, n = len(A), len(B)
    if m > n:
        ## Making sure that A refers to the smaller array
        A, B, m, n = B, A, n, m
    if n == 0:
        raise ValueError

    imin, imax, half_len = 0, m, (m + n + 1) / 2
    while imin <= imax:
        i = (imin + imax) / 2
        j = half_len - i
        if i < m and B[j-1] > A[i]:
            # i is too small, must increase it
            imin = i + 1
        elif i > 0 and A[i-1] > B[j]:
            # i is too big, must decrease it
            imax = i - 1
        else:
            # i is perfect

            if i == 0: max_of_left = B[j-1]
            elif j == 0: max_of_left = A[i-1]
            else: max_of_left = max(A[i-1], B[j-1])

            if (m + n) % 2 == 1:
                return max_of_left

            if i == m: min_of_right = B[j]
            elif j == n: min_of_right = A[i]
            else: min_of_right = min(A[i], B[j])

            return (max_of_left + min_of_right) / 2.0
```

Comment: Run through both versions by hand and count the operations. Which one uses fewer operations?

Comment: Thanks - @MadPhysicist that was actually my unstated guess (that it was a performance choice to get O(log(min(m,n))), but I wasn't sure and maybe you are confirming it. The reason is truly performance? In other words, the same algorithm work correctly regardless of what array I choose to drive the binary search?

Comment: Don't guess. Walk through both options when you have a question and compare the steps and results.

Comment: The solution has complexity `O(log(min(m,n)))` as you can see in the editorial, so choosing the smaller array is definitely beneficial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By enforcing `m <= n`, we make sure both `i` and `j` are always **non-negative**.

Also, we are able to reduce some redundant boundary checks in the while loop when working with `i` and `j`.

Take the first `if` condition in the while loop as an example, the code checks for `i < m` before accessing `A[i]`, but why wouldn't it also check for `j-1 >= 0` before accessing `B[j-1]`? This is because `i` falls into [0, m], and `j = (m + n + 1) / 2 - i`, so when `i` is the largest, `j` is the smallest.
When `i < m`, `j = (m + n + 1)/2 - i > (m + n + 1)/2 - m = n/2 - m/2 + 1/2 >= 0`. So `j` must be positive when `i < m`, and `j - 1 >= 0`.

Similarly, in the second `if` condition in the while loop, when `i > 0`, `j` is guaranteed to be less than `n`.

To verify this idea, you can try removing the size check and swap logic at the top, and run through below example input, in which A is longer than B.

```
[1,2,3,4,6]
[5]
```